# change live wallpaper when idle?

Tags: android

Hi I'm just wondering is there an option or an app in android that will control the android live wallpaper when it's idle? For instance I have a live wallpaper that consumes a tremendous amount of battery and 90% of the time I don't even see the live wallpaper since my phone is in my pocket idle. Is there something that can control this? Like an app that automatically changes the background to an image instead when it's idle and as soon as it comes out of idle mode changes back to the live wp?